# Running Quokka with Apache instead of Nginx

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx

I am installing Quokka from this article: https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/install-quokka-on-a-centos-vps/

Now, I think that everything will work great, but the trouble is that I have Apache on my server instead of Nginx. Most of my websites have some specific .htaccess rules, so if I change from Apache to Nginx just for adjusting to this tutorial, I will have further headaches in configuring Nginx for my existing websites.

I hope that this community will help me with a working Apache virtual host configuration that will be the working alternative to this one:

```html
server {
        server_name YOUR_QUOKKA_DOMAIN;
 client_body_in_file_only clean;
 client_body_buffer_size 64K;
 client_max_body_size 40M;
 sendfile on;
        send_timeout 300s;
        location ~ ^/(static|mediafiles)/ {
            root    /home/quokka/quokka-env/quokka/quokka;
            location ~* ^.+.(py|pyc|sh|bat|ini|pot|git)$ {deny all; }
            expires 7d;
        }
        location / {
            uwsgi_pass      unix:/home/quokka/quokka-env/quokka/etc/logs/quokka.socket;
            include         /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
            uwsgi_param     UWSGI_SCHEME $scheme;
            uwsgi_param     SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;
        }
}
```

I am very grateful for every answer provided, if any. :)

Answer (score 0):

The apache HOME_DIR has the folder vhost.d (or site-avaliables, it depends of you version of apache and/or OS). 
There has a sample of configuration of vhosts, you can use that for start.